# User picture in header section of Java project with Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, authentication, thymeleaf

I am developing a Java project with Spring and Thymeleaf.
I have configured users with a working class which stores a String for a picture, stored on the server.
It works just fine and I invoke it in the main block successfully. In the upper part of my project I have a navigational panel, which is described in my header part of the html. The full html looks like this:
layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">

<head th:include="fragments/head" th:with="pageTitle='Java Project'"></head>

<body>

<header th:include="fragments/header"></header>

<main th:include="${view}"></main>

<footer th:include="fragments/footer"></footer>

<span th:include="fragments/scripts-bundle"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I successfully invoke the user.picture in the main block where the view variable is defined, as per the upper code provided. This is a working example:

This is a view in the main block:

```
……
<th:block th:each="user : ${users}">
    <tr th:class="${user.isAdmin() ? 'info' : null}">
    …………
    <td> <img class="img-circle" th:src="@{/images/users/{picture}(picture=${user.picture})}" height="43" width="43"/></td>
………
</tr>
</th:block>
……
```

The view is invoked by this portion of code in the Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String listUsers(Model model){
List<User> users = this.userRepository.findAll();

model.addAttribute("users", users);
model.addAttribute("view", "admin/user/list");

return "layout";
}
```

In User class I have:

```
….
private String picture;

public String getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public void setPicture(String picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}
…..
```

Everything works fine.

Now I want to invoke the same code like in the view, but to do it in the fragments/header section where the navigation panel is described.
I cannot do this successfully.
As per my modest knowledge I see 2 ways of doing this:

1/ Inject the user by controller code in the thymeleaf view:
Tried something like:

```
@GetMapping("/fragments/header")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public String setPicHead(Model model){
    UserDetails principal = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication()
            .getPrincipal();

    User user = this.userRepository.findByEmail(principal.getUsername());

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("fragments/header", user);

    return "fragments/header";
}

In the fragments/header html I added:
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <img class="img-circle" th:src="@{/images/users/(picture=${user.picture})}" height="43" width="43"/>
</li>
```

Does not work at all and locks the whole Project

2/ The second approach will be I guess to invoke the user independently using the Thymeleaf capabilities. I guess
this can be done, as Thymeleaf has full engine capabilities.

Could anyone help me with this one ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Do it by injection here:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {

    UserDetails principal = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    User user = this.userRepository.findByEmail(principal.getUsername());

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("view", "home/index");

    return "layout";
}
```

In the header section it is like this:

```
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                        <img class="img-circle" th:src="@{/images/users/{one}(one=${user.picture})}" height="49" width="49"/>
                    </li>
```

I would be glad though if someone share solution with direct authentication in Thymeleaf.